# Qt QRegExp with whitespace did not work

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to Qt. I want to check the input value of the QLineEdit: if the input starts with whitespace, turn the font color to black, else make it red. But It doesn't work well.

**Here is the code:**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);


}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_textChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    QRegExp  regexp("^\s*");

    if(!regexp.exactMatch(arg1))
    {
        ui->lineEdit->setStyleSheet("color:red");
    } else

    {
        ui->lineEdit->setStyleSheet("color:black");
    }

}
```

So when I run this code and start with space,It turns red , I can't figure out why this happen.

**UPDATED QUESTION**

Here is what I think:
  If I want to mark red when the input does not digit ,the RegExp should like this:

```
void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_textChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    QRegExp  regexp("^[0-9]*");

    if(regexp.exactMatch(arg1)) {
        ui->lineEdit->setStyleSheet("color:black");//if the input is digits,black
    } else {
        ui->lineEdit->setStyleSheet("color:red");//not digits,red
    }
}
```

And It work as I wanted . But when I add `\s` in RegExp(`QRegExp regexp("^\s[0-9]*")`),digits start with whitespaces or pure digits are turning red. Why is  that?

Comment: First of all, you can use \S (note the cap) to match a non-whitespace character. Also, check the double negation in your logic. Let's say 'A' is 'arg1 begins with a whitespace'. Then your regexp search for match of 'not A'. And then you reverse the boolean value of the exact match (i.e. the '!'), meaning that you check for 'not not A', in other words, for 'A'. Therefore the current logic puts strings begining with a whitespace in red, black otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for your help,But I think that's not the case ,I changed the code to :
    QRegExp  regexp("^\s*");

        if(regexp.exactMatch(arg1))
        {
            ui->lineEdit->setStyleSheet("color:black");
        }else
        {
            ui->lineEdit->setStyleSheet("color:red");
        }

still not work ,when input is several white spaces "         " for example ,the lineedit font color is still red.

Comment: I see where I got wrong,I should use "\\s" insteal of "\s",Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with your code.
First of all, using regexp to solve this task is overkill. You just need to check if the very first char of the string is whitespace. If you need to check the equality to the simple space character (0x20), you can use [QString::startsWith](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#startsWith) function: `arg1.startsWith(' ')`. Or if you need to take into account any whitespace character you can use [QChar::isSpace](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchar.html#isSpace) method:

```
bool stringDoesStartWithWhitespace = false;
if (!arg1.isEmpty()) {
    stringDoesStartWithWhitespace = arg1[0].isSpace();
}
```

This leads us to these variants of the code:

```
void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_textChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    if (arg1.startsWith(' ')) {
        ui->lineEdit->setStyleSheet("color:black");
    } else {
        ui->lineEdit->setStyleSheet("color:red");
    }
}
```

or:

```
void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_textChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    bool stringDoesStartWithWhitespace = false;
    if (!arg1.isEmpty()) {
        stringDoesStartWithWhitespace = arg1[0].isSpace();
    }

    if (stringDoesStartWithWhitespace) {
        ui->lineEdit->setStyleSheet("color:black");
    } else {
        ui->lineEdit->setStyleSheet("color:red");
    }
}
```

Now let's take a look at the regular expression (if you *really* need to use one). You should *escape* the backslash for it to be seen as a part of the regular expression and not as a part of the escape sequence (`\s`). You can read [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) about escape sequences.
Also, as I did understand, you need to make the control foreground color black if the input starts with at least one space. In this case, you should use `+` symbol instead of `*` (`E+` is for matching one or more occurrences of `E`). You can read about quantifiers [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexp.html#quantifiers).
Second, QRegExp using. [QRegExp::exactMatch](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexp.html#exactMatch) page says that this function

> Returns `true` if string is matched **exactly** by this regular expression; otherwise returns `false`.

In your case you just need to check if the beginning of the QTextEdit value is matched by regexp. You should use [QRegExp::indexIn](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexp.html#indexIn) function.

As the result, your code will be something like this:

```
void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_textChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    QRegExp regexp("^\\s+");

    if (regexp.indexIn(arg1) > -1) {    //we do have the whitespace in the beginning of the string
        ui->lineEdit->setStyleSheet("color:black");
    } else {
        ui->lineEdit->setStyleSheet("color:red");
    }
}
```

Comment: I see where I might be wrong,so if I use "\s" in QRegExp ,the code would find the match for "s",and what I really need to do is use "\\s",and if I want to
find digits I should use "\\d" instead of "\d",right?Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's not that simple. '\s' in the string literal treated as an unknown escape sequence. As stated in the c++ standard, "Escape sequences
in which the character following the backslash is not listed in Table 6 are conditionally-supported, with implementation-defined semantics." It means, that result literal will depend on compiler. For instance, VC++ will interpret '\s' in string literal as a simple 's' char. All in all, it's better not to use unknown escape sequences.

Comment: Thanks for the tip,as you mentioned ,I figure regular expression indeed have some differences in other languages.